# PHP Upload multiple images and check their file extensions prior

Tags: php

I have the following code to upload a file to a folder, depending on the file input upload the file is renamed e.g. the first input - the picture is renamed to picture01.jpg, the 5th input - the picture is renamed to picture to picture01.jpg, etc...

```
<form action="upload_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <p><input name="image01" type="file"> </p>
    <p><input name="image02" type="file"> </p>
    <p><input name="image03" type="file"> </p>
    <p><input name="image04" type="file"> </p>
    <p><input name="image05" type="file"> </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>
```

This is upload_file.php -

```
<?php 

$pic_names = array (
    '01' => 'picture01',
    '02' => 'picture02',
    '03' => 'picture03',
    '04' => 'picture04',
    '05' => 'picture05',
                    );


$folder = "temp_images/"; 

if(preg_match("/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|mp4)/",$ext)) {
// Picture01
$image_path01 = $folder . $pic_names['01'] . '.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image01']['tmp_name'], $image_path01);
// Picture02
$image_path02 = $folder . $pic_names['02'] . '.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image02']['tmp_name'], $image_path02);
// Picture03
$image_path03 = $folder . $pic_names['03'] . '.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image03']['tmp_name'], $image_path03);
// Picture04
$image_path04 = $folder . $pic_names['04'] . '.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image04']['tmp_name'], $image_path04);
// Picture05
$image_path05 = $folder . $pic_names['05'] . '.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image05']['tmp_name'], $image_path05);

    echo 'Uploaded successfully!';
   } else { echo 'Uploaded successfully!';}
    ?>
```

I would like to check that before the file is uploaded it is checked that either one of the following extensions exist prior to uploading jpg, gif or png. If they have another extension then it is not uploaded and an error is given.

The only solution I managed to find is when the input name="**image**" type="file"> have the same name e.g. in this case **name**. How can I do it for my case with different names for the input?

I got the follwoing error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE

Though I am sure that it more than a parse error.

Any suggestion or help please?

UPDATE: I amended the code but its telling me that 'Wrong file type!' for any image format too.

Comment: `echo 'Uploaded successfully!';` must be before `}`, not after it

Comment: I updated my answer but still it didn't work.

Comment: Add attribute `accept='image/*'`

Comment: From a security point of view I wish that uploads are be validated on the server.

Comment: _"The only solution I managed to find is when the input name="image" type="file"> have the same name e.g. in this case name. How can I do it for my case with different names for the input?"_

Haven't you already done that, by repeating the same code 5 times?

Comment: The names in my above code are different all the time for every instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in both string `echo 'Uploaded successfully!';{` position and content.

1) No any statements is allowed between `}` and `else`.

2) `'Uploaded successfully!';{` contains `{` which is superfluous.

**Update:** One of a quite good ways to process uploaded files. Depends on $pic_names array from OP.

```
$pic_names = array (
    '01' => 'picture01',
    '02' => 'picture02',
    '03' => 'picture03',
    '04' => 'picture04',
    '05' => 'picture05',
);

$allowed_mime = array(
    'image/jpeg' => 'jpg',
    'image/pjpeg' => 'jpg',
    'image/gif' => 'gif',
    'image/png' => 'png',
);

$upload_messages = array(
    UPLOAD_ERR_OK => ' Uploaded successfully!',
    UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE => ' The uploaded file exceeds the maxumum size of ' . ini_get('upload_max_filesize') . '.',
    UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL => ' The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.',
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE => ' No file was uploaded',
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => ' Missing a temporary folder.',
    UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => ' Failed to write file to disk.',
    UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION => ' A PHP extension stopped the file upload.',
    100 => ' Wrong file type.',
);

$folder = "temp_images/"; 

$error_message = $success_message = '';
$upload_counter = 0;

foreach ($pic_names as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($_FILES['image'.$key]) && !$_FILES['image'.$key]['error']) {
        $file_mime = getFileMime($_FILES['image'.$key]['tmp_name']);

        if ( in_array($file_mime, array_keys($allowed_mime)) ) {
            $new_path = $folder . $value . '.' . $allowed_mime[$file_mime];

            if ( !move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image'.$key]['tmp_name'], $new_path) ) {
                $error_message .= ' Image' . $key . ':' . $upload_messages[UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE];
            } else {
                $upload_counter++;
            }
        } else {
            $error_message .= ' Image' . $key . ':' . $upload_messages[100];
        }
    } else {
        $error_message .= ' Image' . $key . ':' . ($_FILES['image'.$key]['error'] ? $upload_messages[$_FILES['image'.$key]['error']] : $upload_messages[UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE]);
    }
}

if ( $upload_counter == count($pic_names) ) {
    echo $upload_messages[UPLOAD_ERR_OK];
} else {
    echo 'Loaded ' . $upload_counter . ' file' . ($upload_counter != 1 ? 's' : '') . '.' . $error_message;
}

function getFileMime ($file) {
    if (PHP_VERSION >= '5.3.0') {
        $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        return $finfo->file($file);
    } else {
        return mime_content_type($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: I amended the code but its telling me that 'Wrong file type!' for any image format too.

Comment: `echo 'Wrong file type!'; var_dump($ext);`? It would be my fist step for debugging this code.

Comment: Its telling me _Wrong file type!NULL_ Could it be because $ext is not defined?

Comment: @PannyMonium, Problem was a bit more than undefined $ext. ))) I wrote new version.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
echo 'Uploaded successfully!';{
else { echo 'Uploaded successfully!';}
```

to

```
echo 'Uploaded successfully!';
} else { echo 'Wrong file type';}
```